# SQL Server xml select values with partial match

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, partial

My question is about selecting a value from an xml column where the first part matches another column.

I.e. I have this xml:-

```
<PREFS>
    <HIERARCHY>
        <VALUE>[Hierarchy].[Country Name].&amp;[IRELAND]</VALUE>
        <VALUE>[Hierarchy].[Group Name].&amp;[IRELAND]&amp;[Ireland East Hospitals]</VALUE>
        <VALUE>[Hierarchy].[Hospital Name].&amp;[IRELAND]&amp;[IR003]&amp;[St Vincent's Hospital]</VALUE>
    </HIERARCHY>
</PREFS>
```

And I want to select out just the Value that starts with 
[Hierarchy].[Group Name]  - which is the result of another query.

My sql looks like this, I'm in the middle of a loop and the value I'm looking for is in a variable and is re-coded up a hierarchy so it's a bit messy:-

```
SELECT 
    a.prefs.value('(/PREFS/HIERARCHY/VALUE/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') as [ReportValue]
FROM (SELECT @User_defaults as [prefs] ) a  -- a sql variable of XMl type contains the XML
CROSS APPLY (   
-- Returns the thing I'm looking for i.e. "[Hierarchy].[Group Name]"
        SELECT  p.prompt
        FROM @prompts p
        WHERE UPPER(p.prompt) LIKE CASE WHEN  @prompt = '[Hierarchy].[Group Name]' 
                                            THEN '%COUNTRY%' 
                                        WHEN  @prompt = '[Hierarchy].[Hospital Name]' 
                                            THEN '%GROUP%'
                                        ELSE 'XXXXXXXX' -- don't match
                                    END 
        AND p.Parametername LIKE 'HC__%'
            ) s
WHERE
    -- The bit where I just select the Value that matches, but it doesn't work! 
    LEFT(a.prefs.value('(/PREFS/HIERARCHY/VALUE/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)'),len(s.prompt) ) = s.prompt
```

It returns only the fist match, second time round the loop, no results, I can't quite figure out how to partial match, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are happy with a contains check you can do something like this:

```sql
declare @User_defaults xml;

set @User_defaults = '
<PREFS>
    <HIERARCHY>
        <VALUE>[Hierarchy].[Country Name].&amp;[IRELAND]</VALUE>
        <VALUE>[Hierarchy].[Group Name].&amp;[IRELAND]&amp;[Ireland East Hospitals]</VALUE>
        <VALUE>[Hierarchy].[Hospital Name].&amp;[IRELAND]&amp;[IR003]&amp;[St Vincent''s Hospital]</VALUE>
    </HIERARCHY>
</PREFS>'

select @User_defaults.value('(/PREFS/HIERARCHY/VALUE[contains(text()[1], sql:column("s.prompt"))])[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
from (
     -- Your query returning thing to look for
     select N'[Hierarchy].[Group Name]' as prompt
     ) as s
```

Use sql:column to get the value from your derived table into the xQuery expression.

Comment: Thanks Mikael that's just what I needed. I saw your posts on other questions and that made me sign up to ask this question (didn't expect you to actually answer it! Cheers)

Comment: For XQuery Functions against the xml Data Type, see here:

<https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189254.aspx>

Comment: Thanks Brennan, yep dunno how I missed all those!